# Is it possible to use Microsoft Kinect SDK for coding an application to be used with Primesense Carmine 1.09 Sensor?

Tags: kinect

is it possible to use Microsoft Kinect SDK for coding an application to be used with Primesense Carmine 1.09 Sensor?

Does the Kinect SDK recognize the hardware calibration of Primesense Carmine 1.09 especially that is Short Range 0.35M ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be no, since the SDK is developed by Microsoft, and the Carmine 1.09 is used mainly for short range, while Kinect is designed for ranges upwards of 800mm. However [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/) has support for Primesense.